# can't see desktop except for background when log in Ubuntu14.04

Tags: unity, 14.04, gnome, compiz

I need some help, I installed Ubuntu 14.04 from 12.04. I had some problems when it rebooted so I had to install unity using sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop and continue tu update all packages using the virtual console. Ctr + Alt + F1.

But when I tried to login, after entering my user and password nothing loads, no dash, no launcher, etc. I tried everything but most I find is for older versions so I need help with this version or how to install a Gnome panel to replace unity and set it as defaul.

using ccsm show the unity plugin checked.

P.D.: I'm using an Acer Aspire 4520 with and Nvidia card.

Comment: If you create a new account and log in to that, do you still get the problem?

Comment: I can't access anymore than login screen, even the guest account gives the same problem. I'm not very good using the console so I don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: It is probably a Nouveau bug. Can you try booting from the 14.04.1 ISO image and see if that works?

Comment: You can run `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current` from the text console to switch from nouveau to nvidia. Just reboot after it's done installing for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Well I tried that but didn't work and when switching forma grafic to virtual console the screen turns flashy and I cant ese anything. To resolve this I have to use an external monitor. By this moment I think that fresh installation is my solution.

Comment: Sorry to double comment but I had to reinstall Ubuntu, I think this question should be closed

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem but I don't remember what I did exactly.
I'd suggest that if you installed anything that has to do with nvidia drivers, first remove them by running `sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*`. 
Then run the following commands and afterwards reboot your system:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xorg
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

This way, you can make sure that everything works with the default drivers and only afterwards try to install nvidia stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> to open Terminal.
Type `dconf reset -f /org/compiz/` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
Then type `setsid unity` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> then restart your machine.